# traversing in jquery DOM failed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove the inputs when I click the button. Below is my DOM

[image]

I tried but didn't work.

```
$('#changePassword').click(function(){
            $(this).find('.modal-body .inputWrap input').remove();
        });
```

I also `tried $(this).find('.modal-body .inputWrap input').remove();`

Comment: Read the jQuery docs about how .find() works. It doesn't search in the direction you think it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.modal-body` element is not an descendant of the `#changePassword` element, so using `$(this).find(...)` will not return any element.

Instead `model-body` is a ancestor of the button, so you can use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find it then use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) on that element to find the target input elements

```
$('#changePassword').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.modal-body').find('.inputWrap input').remove();
});
```

Comment: ah I did a careless mistake there. I found that if I do $(this).closest('.modal-body').find('.inputWrap input').val(), it will get single value only, how do I loop true to ensure everyone of them has something?

Comment: @JamesLemon yes.. when you use an getter version of a method like `.val()`, it will return the value of the first matching element in the set... you can use [each()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) to iterate an get all the values

Comment: @JamesLemon like `$(this).closest('.modal-body').find('.inputWrap input').each(function () {
    console.log(this, $(this).val(), this.value)
})`

Comment: $(this).val() and this.value is the same?

Comment: But if I do like this `$(this).closest('.modal-body').find('.inputWrap input').each(function(){

    if(this.value != ""){
     console.log('all filled');
    }

  });
`
it will not check for all input, if one input has something the console will fired.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72894/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-james-lemon).

Answer (score 0):

Inside `$('#changePassword').click`, `this` refers to `#changePassword`, which is a sibling of the `.inputWrap` you're searching for.  You need to navigate sideways in the DOM, not down.

```js
$('#changePassword').click(function () {
  $(this).prev('.inputWrap').find('input').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="inputWrap">
    <input type="text" value="where">
    <input type="text" value="who">
  </div>
  <button id="changePassword">Click!</a>
</div>
```